# CSP Out of memory with CryptVerifySignature

Tags: windows, cryptography, openssl, pem

I have an issue with CryptVerifySignature returning NTE_NO_MEMORY (The CSP ran out of memory during the operation.)

I'm trying to verify an signature generated with OpenSSL, I've already decoded a PEM public key, reversed the byte-sequence and imported it.

I've tried explicity specifying the MS Enhanced Provider, and my key length is 4096-bits (<16384-bits max).

I've seen some comments on forums suggesting memory alignment issues, but I'm on an Intel Pentium Dual-Core, and my buffers are 32-bit aligned.

Any one seen this problem before?

Comment: It would help if you could us the code and the data that fails.

Comment: Actually the problem has gone away now. It disappeared when I changed from using the RSA_sign OpenSSL function to the RSA_private_encrypt function to generate signatures. I think it's something to do including an algorithm identifier.

Comment: @jarmond: Please post how your problem has gone away as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to know that the problem is solved by sing RSA_private_encrypt.
My case is reverse of you. I signed using CryptSignHash and verify it using RSA_verify.

I noticed that byte order of signature generated by CryptSignHash and RSA_sign for the same data is exactly reverse. Check out this [link](http://www.linuxhorizon.com/5-openssl/690a879d1bc3eb7e.htm).

Please try to reverse the bytes and see if it works for you.

I have successfully done sign using CryptSignHash and verify using RSA_verify and it is perfectly working.